# How to present an UIViewController in Swift Playgrounds for macOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have Swift Playgrounds v3.2 downloaded from AppStore on my macOS device. I would like to present an instance of the UIViewController class in an empty project. I tried to present it like in the Xcode playground with `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc` but it doesn't worked.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

let vc = UIViewController()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import `UIKit`

Then set the view of the UIViewController to liveView like so

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```